# "OSError: [Errno 17] File exists" when trying to use os.makedirs

Tags: python, file-io, filesystems, queue, cluster-computing

I have several threads running in parallel from Python on a cluster system. Each python thread outputs to a directory `mydir`. Each script, before outputting checks if *mydir* exists and if not creates it:

```
if not os.path.isdir(mydir):
    os.makedirs(mydir)
```

but this yields the error:

```
os.makedirs(self.log_dir)                                             
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name,mode)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists
```

I suspect it might be due to a race condition, where one job creates the *dir* before the other gets to it. Is this possible? If so, how can this error be avoided?

I'm not sure it's a race condition so was wondering if other issues in Python can cause this odd error.

Comment: For those who are stuck with legacy code, see also [How to workaround `exist_ok` missing on Python 2.7?](/q/45283093).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Any time code can execute between when you check something and when you act on it, you will have a race condition. One way to avoid this (and the usual way in Python) is to just try and then handle the exception

```
while True:
    mydir = next_dir_name()
    try:
        os.makedirs(mydir)
        break
    except OSError, e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise   
        # time.sleep might help here
        pass
```

If you have a lot of threads trying to make a predictable series of directories this will still raise a lot of exceptions, but you will get there in the end. Better to just have one thread creating the dirs in that case

Comment: Why do you have the `break` in there?  That loop will only create one directory.

Comment: [**Do not**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) use hardcoded constants! Use [`errno.EEXIST`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/errno.html#errno.EEXIST) instead of magic number (`17`). If you want more elegant solution of your problem see [@Jahid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30174982/1321680).

Comment: @patryk.beza, thanks. Jahid's answer would be the better way for most people these days.

Answer (score 157):

As of Python `>=3.2`, `os.makedirs()` can take a third optional argument `exist_ok`:

```
os.makedirs(mydir, exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 19):

Catch the exception and, if the errno is 17, ignore it. That's the only thing you can do if there's a race condition between the `isdir` and `makedirs` calls.

However, it could also be possible that a *file* with the same name exists - in that case `os.path.exists` would return `True` but `os.path.isdir` returns false.

Comment: What about using `exist_ok` parameter [`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.html?highlight=makedirs#os.makedirs) as of Python 3.2? (I'm asking because have never actually used it).

Comment: @ovgolovin, looks like that would work ok, but not many us get to just support 3.2 yet :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issues and here is what I did

```
try:
   if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(mydir)):
       os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(mydir))
except OSError as err:
   print(err)
```

**Description:**
Just checking if the directory already exist throws this error message **[Errno 17] File exists**
because we are just checking if the ***directory name*** exist or not which will return the directory name of the **mydir** value being passed but not if it already exist or not. What is being missed is not checking if that directory already exist which can be done by checking the path with **os.path.exists()** and in there we passed the respective directory name.

Comment: i was creating symlinks but not checking if they are already created. Important check. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the dir or file exist error, you can try this:

```
    except OSError, e:
        if e.errno != 17:
            print("Error:", e)
```