# How to make 80 folders using Python

Tags: python, for-loop, google-colaboratory

I want to make 79 folder in my drive and want folder name is a number 1 to 79.
this is my code.
I used Google colab

```
import os
for i in range(1,80):
  folder = "/content/drive/My Drive/project/Dataset"
  os.makedirs(folder[i])
```

Please Help.
My code can be change if you have any thought.

Comment: How about `os.makedirs(f"{folder}/{i}")`

Comment: You're code is trying to create 79 folders (your title states it should be 80) and it's trying to create folders for each of the letters as you loop through the individual characters of your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import os

folder = "/content/drive/My Drive/project/Dataset"
for i in range(1,80):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(folder,str(i)))
```

Comment: FileExistsError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-8f8c7464c038> in <module>
      1 for i in range(1,80):
      2     folder = "/content/drive/My Drive/project/Dataset/"
----> 3     os.mkdir(os.path.join(folder,str(i)))

FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/content/drive/My Drive/project/Dataset/1'

Comment: It's not work. It's show " File exists: '/content/drive/My Drive/project/Dataset/1 "

Comment: It worked on mine. You probably already have that folder created. Add `os.makedirs` with `exist_ok=True`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468022/python-fileexists-error-when-making-directory